# How to add filters to a query dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

In my viewSet I am doing a query,

```
queryset= Books.objects.all();
```

Now from an ajax call I get my filter values from UI i.e. age,gender, etc. of auther.There will be a total of 5 filters.

Now the problem which I ran into is how am I going to add filters to my query(only those filters which have any value).

What I tried is I checked for individual filter value and did query, but that way it fails as if the user remove the filter value or add multiple filters.
Any better suggestion how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a bit more generic one. It will apply filters to your queryset if they are passed as the `GET` parameters. If you're doing a `POST` call, just change the name in the code.

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q


def your_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Here you list all your filter names
    filter_names = ('filter_one', 'filter_two', 'another_one', )

    queryset = Books.objects.all(); 
    filter_clauses = [Q(filter=request.GET[filter])
                      for filter in filter_names
                      if request.GET.get(filter)]
    if filter_clauses:
        queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, filter_clauses))

    # rest of your view
```

Note that you can use lookup expressions in your filters' names. For example, if you want to filter books with price lower or equal to specified in filter, you could just use `price__lte` as a filter name.

Comment: This is more DRY than my answer. I think it's easier to understand my answer first, so the two answers work well together :)

Comment: Note you might want `request.GET.get(filter)` instead of `filter in request.GET`, they give different results if the empty string is submitted.

Comment: @Alasdair, nice catch, thank you! Updated the answer with your suggestion. You're totally right, I personally don't like the `reduce` part of my answer, wish we could express it more pythonically.

Comment: Is it ok if i have my filters fields 'filter_one' 'filter_two' etc in different models.

Comment: @AmanGupta, yes, Django allows you to query the linked models' fields also: `filters = ('a_book_field', 'author__an_author_field', )` etc. It's totally fine to mix them.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this, but it always says `Cannot resolve keyword 'filter' into field`. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you've misspelled a field name in your `filter_names` list.

Comment: I got the same as @jinchuika, any fix? the problem is that filter_cluase would contain something like this `filter_clauses 
[<Q: (AND: ('filter', u'1'))>]`

Comment: How should we pass the filter values to the view? What is the object structure of filter in request.GET[filter]?? Please help.

Answer (score 13):

You haven't shown any code, so you haven't really explained what the problem is:

Start with the queryset `Book.objects.all()`. For each filter, check if there is a value for the filter in `request.POST`, and if so, filter the queryset. Django querysets are lazy, so only the final queryset will be evaluated.

```
queryset = Book.objects.all()
if request.POST.get('age'):
    queryset = queryset.filter(author__age=request.POST['age'])
if request.POST.get('gender'):
    queryset = queryset.filter(author__gender=request.POST['gender'])
...
```

Comment: its worth mentioning that they're only evaluated when the results are needed :) +1 anywho

Answer (score 5):

You can simply get the request.GET content as a dict (making sure to convert the values to string or a desired type as they'd be list by default i.e: `dict(request.GET)` would give you something like `{u'a': [u'val']}`.

Once you are sure you have a dictionary of keys matching your model fields, you can simply do:

`filtered = queryset.filter(**dict_container)`

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me, I've merged Alex Morozov answer with [Dima answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436777/django-filtering-with-q-objects-with-dynamic-fields)

```
import operator

def your_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Here you list all your filter names
    filter_names = ('filter_one', 'filter_two', 'another_one', )

    queryset = Books.objects.all(); 
    filter_clauses = [Q(**{filter: request.GET[filter]})
                  for filter in filter_names
                  if request.GET.get(filter)]
    if filter_clauses:
    queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, filter_clauses))

    # rest of your view
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) would help simplify the solutions others have given?

Something like:

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['author__age', 'author__gender', ...]
```

Then the view looks like:

```
def book_list(request):
    f = BookFilter(request.GET, queryset=Book.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('my_app/template.html', {'filter': f})
```

For more information see the [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
class BooksAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Books.objects.none()


def get_queryset(self):
    argumentos = {}
    if self.request.query_params.get('age'):
        argumentos['age'] = self.request.query_params.get('age')
    if self.request.query_params.get('gender'):
        argumentos['gender'] = self.request.query_params.get('gender')
    if len(argumentos) > 0:
        books = Books.objects.filter(**argumentos)
    else:
        books = Books.objects.all()
    return books
```

Comment: I want range filter in age then what should I have to do

Comment: `if self.request.query_params.get('age'):     argumentos['age__gte'] = self.request.query_params.get('age')    argumentos['age__lte'] = self.request.query_params.get('age')` .    @Deepak Chawla

Answer (score 1):

For a very simple **equality** check, here is my solution using a helper function in a ModelViewSet.

1. The helper function `check_for_params` creates a dictionary of request parameters passed in the URL.
2. Alter the ModelViewSet `get_queryset()` method by filtering the Django QuerySet with a single filter clause which prevents [multiple queries being called by chaining filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

I could tried to use the Django Q() object but could not get it to only make a single call.

```
def check_for_params(request, param_check_list: List) -> dict:
    """
    Create a dictionary of params passed through URL.

    Parameters
    ----------
    request - DRF Request object.
    param_check_list - List of params potentially passed in the url.
    """
    if not param_check_list:
        print("No param_check_list passed.")
    else:
        param_dict = {}
        for p in param_check_list:
            param_dict[p] = request.query_params.get(p, None)
        return param_dict
    

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return a queryset and apply filters, if applicable.
        
        Info
        ----
        Building the queryset.filter method by unpacking the key-value pairs this way,
        creates a single filter clause and prevents multiple queries from being called
        by chaining filters.
        """
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

        param_check_list = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']
        params = check_for_params(self.request, param_check_list)
        filtered = {k: v for k, v in params.items() if v}

        # Calling filter() only once here prevents multiple queries. 
        return queryset.filter(**filtered)
```