# How to populate a list looping in another list in Python?

Tags: python, django, list, foreach, request

I am making a search page on Django and want to generate a dynamic queryset.

I have a list of string filters initiaized like this:

`filter_names = ('filter1', 'filter2')`

then, I want to loop in my filter_names list and make a list  of Q objects for each filter that comes in the request (with the same names in filter_names). I am creating the list of Q like this:

```
filter_clauses = [Q(filter=request.GET.get(filter))
                      for filter in filter_names
                      if request.GET.get(filter)]
```

the problem is that the resultant list (filter_clauses) is something like:

```
Q(filter=value1),
Q(filter=value2)
```

But I actually want a list like:

```
Q(filter1=value1),
Q(filter2=value2)
```

In effect, the loop is not catching the value of the variable filter but interpreting it as "filter".

**So, am I doing anything wrong in the loop?**

For more information, I took the idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739680/how-to-add-filters-to-a-query-dynamically-in-django), And I'm getting this error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'filter' into field.

that means, that the framework is searching a field in the searched model with the name 'filter' and obviusly doesn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use keyword argument unpacking:

```
filter_clauses = [Q(**{filter: request.GET.get(filter)})
                      for filter in filter_names
                      if request.GET.get(filter)]
```

Here the *value* of `filter` is the key in the dictionary, so when you unpack the arguments, the parameter name will be `filter1` etc.