# django filtering with q objects with dynamic fields

Tags: django, django-models

I need to prepare filter with dynamic fields.. 
I don't know the field name so i need to give it dynamically.
here what i tried so far,

```
gen_query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(eval('%s=i' % (field, i))) for i in request.query_params.get(field).split(',')))
```

but it raising syntax error!

i am using, `eval(field_name as string)` still i am getting an error..

how to achieve this?

i want to do django filtering with q objects with dynamic fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create dict with parameters and unpack it in Q constructor:

```
gen_query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**{field: i}) for i in request.query_params.get(field).split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `Q('{}={}'.format(field, i))` if you need string formatting?

Comment: this is filter query... i think there is no meaning in it... your code will just do concatenation as i did.. its just an another method

Comment: Not working. :(